# Adding one image to specific UICell using if statement adds it to multiple UICells Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using an if statement so that only specific cells gets images. In my test examples there is only one cell that should get an image and the if statement gets run only once. The if statement also changes the text of the labels. The labels are correctly changed but the image is added to multiple cells especially when I scroll up and down. How to I get it to  not add extra images to other cells.

```
UIImageView *imageView= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(114,5, 122, 63)];
    if (condition) {
    [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
                imageView.tag = 777;
                [cell addSubview:imageView];
                cell.titleLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
                cell.titleDescription.text = [dict valueForKey:@"summary"];
    } else {
                [[cell viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The UITableViewCell is cached, so instead of always creating a new UIImageView, check first if it has one:

```
UIImageView * imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:777];

if (condition) {

    if(!imageView) {
        imageView= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(114,5, 122, 63)];
    }
    [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
    imageView.tag = 777;
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.titleDescription.text = [dict valueForKey:@"summary"];
} else {
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

You were likely adding multiple imageViews to one cell, so removeFromSuperView was only removing the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this 
  during the creation of cell that is

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableVIew dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
      if(cell == nil)
      {
           cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];
         UIImageView *aImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 40, 40)];
       aImgView.tag = 777;
       [cell addSubview:aImgView];
       [aImgView release];
     }

     //use your condition hear onwards to make changes
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
     {
        UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:777];
        view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"peter.png"];

     }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
     {
          if(indexPath.row == 0 )
           {      
              UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:777];
              view.image = nil;
           }
          else
          {
              UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:777];
              view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"peter.png"];

          }

    }

 return cell;

}
```

change according to requirement

note: i am not using ARC